# Vue.js passing array from one page to another

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm using vue.js and I have one component, where the user selects what they want and then they hit "order". At this moment I use `<router-link to="/order">` to show new page. But I don't know how to access the array from the previous component there. I tried something like this `:selected-chairs="selectedChairs"` and in the other component this `props: ['selectedChairs']`, but it doesn't work. 
My routes file (index.js):

```
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Select',
      component: Select,
      props: true
    },
    {
      path: '/order',
      name: 'Order',
      component: Order,
      props: true
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: Are you using Vuex?

Comment: @WaldemarIce no, I don't use Vuex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue: shared data between different pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40953496/vue-shared-data-between-different-pages)

Comment: Show the code for the part where you do `:selected-chairs="selectedChairs"` as this is the right way to go and it should be working

Comment: @webnoob `<router-link to="/order" :selected-chairs="selectedChairs" v-if="selectedChairs.length <= 20" class="button-v1" v-on:click="order">
                                Rezervovat
                            </router-link>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to do what you want to do but I don't think it's a good idea. First, in line with your original question, this is what you could do:

Set up your order route:

```
export default new Router({
    routes: [{
      path: '/order/:selected-chairs',
      name: 'Order',
      component: Order,
      props: true
    }]
}
```

You could then have a link like so:

```
<router-link :to="'/order/' + JSON.stringify(mySelectedChairs) + '">Link Text</router-link>
```

or you could do

```
<router-link :to="{path: 'order', query: { selected-chairs: mySelectedChairs }}">Link Text</router-link>
```

This would allow you to access that data on your component using:

```
this.$route.params.selected-chairs
```

or

```
this.selectedChairs // because props: true binds to the props
```

This page has more information on passing params using `router-link`: https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-link.html

As I said, I don't think this is a good idea. Even if you're not using Vuex, you're much better off doing this using some sort of stateful component. You could then set the `selected-chairs` in your state and the `order` component would *just know* about them being selected. This allows you to do things like having a mini basket that reacts to users entering stuff into their baskets etc.

Setting up a simple Vuex system isn't complicated and there are various articles on the web to help that would be my recommended approach.

Comment: Thank you very much! Helped a lot. I used vuex and it's working just as I need it to :).

Comment: Not a problem and glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is correct but will show a blank page on page load.

To solve that, DO:

```
export default new Router({
    routes: [{
      path: '/order/:selected-chairs?',
      name: 'Order',
      component: Order,
      props: true
    }]
}
```

As you can see, I added a question mark (?) to the front of the path parameter