# VueJS vue-router passing a value to a route

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

In VueJS 2 with vue-router 2 I am using a parent view with subcomponents like this:

WidgetContainer.vue with route /widget_container/:

```
<template>
  <component :is="activeComponent"></component>
</template>

<script>
  import WidgetA from './components/WidgetA'
  import WidgetB from './components/WidgetB'

  export default {
    name: 'WidgetContainer',
    components: {
      WidgetA,
      WidgetB
    },
    data () {
      return {
        activeComponent: 'widget-a'
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

In WidgetA I have the option of selecting a widget id

```
<template>
// v-for list logic here..
<router-link :to="{ path: '/widget_container/' + widget.id }"><span>{{widget.name}}   </span></router-link>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
    name: 'WidgetA',
    data() {
      return {
        widgets: [
          { id: 1,
            name: 'blue-widget'
          }]}}
```

routes.js:

```
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/widget_container',
      component: WidgetContaner
    },
    {
      path: '/widget_container/:id?',
      redirect: to => {
        const { params } = to
        if (params.id) {
          return '/widget_contaner/:id'
        } else {
          return '/widget_container'
        }
      }
    }]})
```

From the WidgetContainer if the route is /widget_container/1 (where '1' is the id selected in WidgetA) I want to render WidgetB, but I cant work out:

1) how to pass the selected widget id into the router-link in WidgetA
2) How to know in WidgetContainer the the route is /widget_contaner/1 instead of /widget_container/ and render WidgetB accordingly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show your router config as well.

Comment: @Saurabh, done see routes.js section. Im really unsure about the path: 'widget_container/:id?' setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass data to parent using by emitting event, you can see more details around [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42757051/web-components-design-pattern/42758505#42758505) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40915436/vuejs-update-parent-data-from-child-component/40915910#40915910).

Once the data is change, you can [watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) over it and update the variable which has stored your widget.

Another option, if communication between components become unmanageable over time is to use some central state management, like [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/), more details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40955110/1610034).

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be easier and more scallable to use Vuex for that?
Just commit id to store and than navigate ?